# Radius of Convergence of Binomial Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Why the following is true?

$$\bigg|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n)}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n+1)}\bigg|=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|\alpha-n|}{n+1}=1$$

This is found in [this link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Binomial_Theorem/General_Binomial_Theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some typo in wiki. The binomial series formula is

$$\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}
{{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^\alpha } = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}} {x^n} \quad \text{which uniformly converges when}{\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} {\mkern 1mu} \left| x \right| < 1}\\
{{a_n} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\alpha \\
n
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{{\prod\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( {\alpha  - i} \right)} }}{{n!}} = \frac{{\alpha \left( {\alpha  - 1} \right)...\left( {\alpha  - \left( {n - 1} \right)} \right)}}{{n!}}}
\end{array}$$

Now consider the following

$$\frac{{{a_{n + 1}}}}{{{a_n}}} = {a_{n + 1}}.\frac{1}{{{a_n}}} = \frac{{\alpha \left( {\alpha  - 1} \right)...\left( {\alpha  - n} \right)}}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}\frac{{n!}}{{\alpha \left( {\alpha  - 1} \right)...\left( {\alpha  - \left( {n - 1} \right)} \right)}} = \frac{{\alpha  - n}}{{n + 1}}$$

I think this solves your confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The first equality holds because all other factors cancel, the second equality holds because for $n\gg \alpha$, $|\alpha-n|=n-\alpha$ and so $\frac{|\alpha-n|}{n+1}=\frac{n-\alpha}{n+1}=1-\frac{\alpha+1}{n+1}$ where the last fraction $\to 0$.

Comment: I don't see how the cancellation works out.

Comment: Can't you see the same factors in Numerator and Denominator such as $\alpha$ or $\alpha -1$ or ...?

Comment: To me it seems like $(\alpha-n+1) > (\alpha-n)$, i.e. what should remain is the $(a-n+1)$ term.

Comment: Let me figure this out! :)

Comment: @mavavilj: Take a look at my answer. :)

Comment: @mavavilj The factors in the numerator go from $\alpha$ **down** to $\alpha-n$ and in the denominator they go from $\alpha$ **down** to $\alpha-n+1$. As $\alpha-n+1>\alpha-n$, the "going down" in the numerator has one final step **more**.